# Using loops and conditionals in component.io reactive

Tags: javascript, templates

Im using [component/reactive](https://github.com/component/reactive) in my project .Anyone who used reactive ,how do i use conditionals like if/else and loops like each/for in my html templates ?

Right now im using component/dom and wrapping the template in it and sending that element to reactive to bind with model.It works great except now i need to use loops in my templates .